# Basic Solidity Questions

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a few questions on solidity and ethereum.

- What’s the difference between EVM and non-EVM calls?
- How do you set a limit on the ether balance of a contract and what
  happens when you try to send more ether to the limited contract?
- How can you set the value of msg.val in a contract acct and not an
  external acct?

I have checked online but cannot seem to find satisfying answers to these questions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What’s the difference between EVM and non-EVM calls?

- EVM calls are smart contract method calls which trigger method execution and requires GAS.
- non-EVM calls are reading values public values. No need to GAS.

How do you set a limit on the ether balance of a contract and what happens when you try to send more ether to the limited contract?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract yourContract{

uint256 public balanceLimit = 999;


   function () payable{
    if (this.balance + msg.value > balanceLimit) {
        throw;
    }
   }
}
```

How can you set the value of msg.val in a contract acct and not an external acct?
msg.val => msg.value =  number of wei sent with the message